# Power Automate Flow How do I use an expression with an email?

Tags: arrays, sharepoint, foreach, power-automate

I'm new to Power Automate and Flow. I created an out of the box "Send an email when a list item is added." The list I created has a field that can have one or more values tied to the Outlook address book called "AssignTo". How do I reference the items in the AssignTo list field with an expression?   Is there a way to use a "for-each" expression inside the Email card?